# how to enable randr on centos7 with nvidia

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, xorg

I want to enable RandR option on Centos7 64-bit system.
But on googling about the issue it seems NVIDIA supports randr1.1 and randr 1.2  but Centos7 by default has randr 1.4 installed.

Relevant details below:

```
[root@box1 ~]# nvidia-smi -L
GPU 0: GeForce GT 710 (UUID: GPU-999ed32f-aef2-0d96-57a5-c91f21c6a15a)

[root@box1 ~]# cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i randr
[   368.340] (**) Extension "RANDR" is enabled
[   368.874] (--) RandR disabled 

[root@box1 ~]# xrandr -v
xrandr program version       1.4.
```

My /etc/X11/xorg.con file below:

```
[root@box1 ~]# cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 384.69  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-06)  Wed Aug 16 20:54:53 PDT 2017

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 384.69  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-06)  Wed Aug 16 20:57:01 PDT 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    FontPath        "/usr/share/fonts/default/Type1"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics W1643"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 50.0
    VertRefresh     57.0 - 63.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 710"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "1360x768 +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "1360x768_60 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection


Section "Extensions"
    Option "Composite" "Enable"
    Option "RANDR" "Enable"
EndSection
```

Tried installing librandr-1.1.1 but its not happening.

Any guidance/support is highly appreciated.

Comment: What has this got to do with Tcl and Tk? Sounds like a system setup issue that belongs on a different Stack Exchange site.

Comment: tcl/tk application is not working properly.